# change location and size of title page logo

Tags: formatting, titles

I have a title thesis with a logo:

[image]

but i would like to get the logo (size 990x369) a little higher and bigger than current result (if I change the size of image it goes down...), also how can I format the name of advisors and synodal?

[image]

I have :

```
\begin{titlepage}
\includegraphics[width=.23  \textwidth]{images/logo.jpg}
% \TitleBlock{\includegraphics[height=2.6cm]{imagenes/logo.png}}
\vspace{+.21in}
\parbox[][3in][s]{6in}{%
        {\vspace{+.05in} \par}
        \centering          
            {\small \textsc{ \bfseries {THE NAME OF THE THESIS GOES RIGHT\\ HERE IT IS A LITTLE LONG BUT IT\\ IS HOW IT IS}} \par}
            \vspace*{\fill}
            {\small \textsc{Thesis presented by} \par}
            \vspace*{\fill}
            {\small \bfseries {The name of the guy doing defending the thesis} \par}
            \vspace*{\fill}
            {\small \textsc{To become} \par}
            \vspace*{\fill}
            {\small \bfseries {\textsc{Ph. D. }} \par}
            \vspace*{\fill}
            {(Certain kind of Ph. D.) \par}
            \vspace*{\fill}     
            \vspace{+.1in}
            \vspace*{\fill}
            \vspace{+.5in}
            \vspace{+.3in}
            {Advisors: \par}
            \vspace*{\fill}     
            {\small \bfseries {Dr. the first name} \par}
            {\small \bfseries {Dr. the second name} \par}           
            \vspace*{\fill}
            \vspace{+.5in}
            {Synodal: \par}
            \vspace*{\fill}     
            {\small \bfseries {Dr. the first name} \par}
            {\small \bfseries {Dr. the second name} \par}
            {\small \bfseries {Dr. the third name } \par}
            \vspace{+.4in}
    \parbox[][.35in][s]{6in}{%
        \vspace*{\fill}
        {\centering
        \textsc{University} \par
        \textsc{Departament} \par
        \textsc{City and Date} \par     
        }
        \vspace*{\fill}
    }
    }
\end{titlepage}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would put the image inside `\raisebox{<height>}{<image>}`.  But that wouldn't be sufficient.  There are two options with `\raisebox` for height and depth.  You can set them both to zero, or if that has adverse effect, set them to some positive value:

```
\raisebox{2in}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{images/logo.jpg}}
```

If you give a fuller MWE which shows the most basic packages you need to load to get the problem you're having, I can write you a fuller (and probably more useful) answer.

When I try to compile what you've got (making a few guesses about packages), I don't see anything that looks problematic.

Comment: ok, I am testing the code you provided, csn you please make a suggestion to give format to the Advisors part, and synodals?

Comment: What you've got looks fine to me.  Doesn't your university have some kind of formatting requirements already for these sorts of thing?  If you can mention what they are, then perhaps I can better help you.

Comment: well, the output pdf is something like the image i posted, but I would like to give format to the advisors... like a kind of list or enum though.